# How to Compile and install Virtual usb?

Tags: installation, compiling

after days of searching I found this [link](http://low-level-world.com/index.html) and seems it has what I've been looking for !
I couldn't install it , I'm so new linux user 
can u give me a hand in this :( 
please

readme file says :

> To compile the driver you need to have source codes of your  OS
>   kernel. Default Makefile is searching  for kernel source  codes in
>   "/usr/src/linux" folder to  compile the driver. If  your  kernel  is 
>   in  the  other  folder  you can point its  location in the file system
>   using KERNELDIR variable.
>
> e.g.: make KERNELDIR=/usr/src/kernel-source-2.6.17.5
>
> After successful driver  compilation there will be tusbd.ko  file  in 
>   the "/modules/src/tusbd/"  folder.  This  file is  necessary for USB
>   Server operation

didn't know what to do !

From a comment to Web-E's answer:

```
sudo ./installer.sh install 
Installing Low-level-world INC USB Server + USB Client...
No kernel module found for your kernel version. Will try to compile from sources.
Compiling kernel module...
Cannot compile kernel module. Installation terminated. See buildlog.txt file for more information. 
make:  /usr/src/linux: No such file or directory. Stop. make:
[clean] Error 2
```

Comment: If you're trying to do USB over ethernet http://usbip.sourceforge.net/ is worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

It seems that the installation is to build a custom kernel. The webpage says it is updated last in 2008. So I doubt it will work with current kernel.

Do the followings,

```
sudp apt-get install linux-source
```

This will download the kernel source. Now execute

`ls -l /usr/src/`

You will see a `.bzip` file symlinked like below

`linux-source-3.5.0.tar.bz2 -> linux-source-3.5.0/linux-source-3.5.0.tar.bz2`

The version `3.5.0` may be different in your case, modify accordingly.

Now execute

```
cd /usr/src
sudo tar --bzip2 -xvf linux-source-3.5.0.tar.bz2
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-source-3.5.0 /usr/src/linux
```

Now go back to the Downloaded virtual usb folder and execute the installer.

This solves the kerneldir issue. Where as still you may face error in compilation as the functions may be broken in recent kernel.

You can see content of `virtual-usb/modules/src/tusbd/buildlog.txt` to see what is going wrong.

You can give a try compiling old kernels but I am not sure and take no responsibility. 
here is a guide for kernel compilation http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=56835

Anyone wants help, please feel free to edit this post.

Comment: safaa@web-dev-2:~/virtual-usb$ sudo ./installer.sh install
 
*** Installing Low-level-world INC USB Server + USB Client...
***  No kernel module found for your kernel version. Will try to compile from sources.
***  Compiling kernel module...
***  Cannot compile kernel module. Installation terminated. See buildlog.txt file for more information.
make: *** /usr/src/linux: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [clean] Error 2